# ¿Cómo aplicar un umbral para graficar un espectrograma con ciertas areas 'resaltadas' usando scipy.sepctrogram?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

mi consulta viene dada porque he visto que en matlab existe un parámetro que permite hacer = 0 a todos aquellos valores que no superan cierto umbral:

De la documentación de matlab.

s = spectrogram(x) devuelve la Transformada de Fourier de tiempo corto (STFT) de la señal de entrada x. Cada columna de s contiene una estimación del contenido de la frecuencia de tiempo corto localizada en el tiempo de x. La magnitud al cuadrado de s se conoce como la representación de tiempo-frecuencia del espectrograma de x [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html).

**MinThreshold — Umbral*
-Inf (predeterminado) | escalar real
Umbral, especificado como un escalar real expresado en decibelios. spectrogram establece en cero esos elementos de s de forma que 10 log10(s) ≤ thresh.*

ejemplo:
[~,~,~,pxx,fc,tc] = spectrogram(y,kaiser(128,18),120,128,Fs, ...
**'MinThreshold'**,-30);

No encontré esta opción en [scipy.signal.spectrogram( )](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) y tal vez alguien sepa como hacerlo,
muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.